# Defined static variable in Expressjs middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, closures

here is the code:

```
   var app = require('express')()
   app.get('/',function(req,res){
            var flag = 0
            console.log(flag)
            res.send('ok')
            flag  ++
    }
    app.listen(3001)
```

every time I request the url '/', it will console '0' which is not I preferred 'plus plus', and I don't want to define the variable outside the express middleware as a global. Would you like tell me how to work variable plus plus in middleware like a static variable.

thanks in advance for the tiny question.

Comment: Don't declare/assign the var inside the callback handler-- do so immediately below `app` and then it should work.

Comment: @AlexanderNied thanks, but I don't want declare outside the callback, I think it is not professional.

Comment: Declaring it outside the callback does not make it global. Node wraps the code in each file in its own function so the `flag` variable won't be accessible outside the current file. If you want to confine it further using `var` you could use an IIFE, or use `let` instead and wrap it in a block.

Comment: @skirtle thanks it's useful, but instead of 'var' with 'let' , the plus plus still not work

Comment: Just changing `var` to `let` won't fix anything, you still need to move the variable outside the function. I mentioned `let` because wrapping it in a block scope would be an alternative to using an IIFE. In practice I'd probably not bother with either as it won't be global anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `locals` property of the `app` object, meant for variables that keep state in your application

```
var app = require('express')();

app.locals.flag = 0;

app.get('/',function(req,res){
   console.log(app.locals.flag);
   res.send('ok');
   app.locals.flag++;
});

app.listen(3001);
```

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals

Comment: Yes this is a good suggestion,Is it possible that using closure solve this problem?

Comment: Not really closures, but you could wrap it in an IIFE to achieve something similar -> https://jsfiddle.net/8jgq034n/ ... I'd much rather used the `locals` property though, as this is what it was intended for